# Basinhopping (two-phase) optimization on multivariate-valued functions

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

#### Background

So far, I've been using [`scipy.optimize.least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) to find a root to a multivalued function `f: R^n -> R^m`. This works great for local optimisation, and I'm trying to find an equivalent for "global" optimization, starting by using two-phase methods (doing global optimization by running many local minimisation wit different initial conditions).

I'd like to do this in [Basinhopping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html), similarly to this:

```
# local
def custom_minimizer(fun, _x0, *args, **kwargs):
    return scipy.optimize.least_squares(fun, _x0)

# global: minimize f starting at x0
ret = basinhopping(
    f,
    x0,
    minimizer_kwargs={"method": custom_minimizer},
)
```

This doesn't work, as basinhopping requires f to output a scalar. However, if I use `lambda x: np.sum(f(x)**2)` instead as an argument of `basinhopping`, the `fun` argument in `custom_minimizer` won't be `f` anymore, and I don't want to lose this information.

#### Question

Can I do multivariate-valued optimization (with a specific norm) using scipy's basinhopping function, or similar two-phase methods? In particular, is there a way to specify the norm and the objective function separately, instead of directly giving the function `x -> norm(f(x))` as an argument?